# For each loop to go to next row in iteration once value found in range

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

All,

I have the below code which iterates through columns and rows to see `IF` the statement is true. It seems to be running through the whole code bringing back duplicate rows. I would like this code to go to the next row once a value has been found.

I'm unsure how to adapt this code but I imagine the issue lies with the general for each loop I have set up any advise on how to fix this would be much appreciated.

```
Dim LR As Long
LR = Workbooks(trackerName).Sheets("Results").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
Dim LRC As Long
LRC = Workbooks(trackerName).Sheets("Columnsforbox").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1
For Each c In Workbooks(trackerName).Sheets("results").Range("A4:K" & LR)
    If c.Value = UserName Or c.Value = UserId Then
        Worksheets("Columnsforbox").Range("A" & LRC) = Worksheets("Results").Range("E" & c.Row)
        Worksheets("Columnsforbox").Range("B" & LRC) = Worksheets("Results").Range("D" & c.Row)
        Worksheets("Columnsforbox").Range("C" & LRC) = Worksheets("Results").Range("A" & c.Row)
        Worksheets("Columnsforbox").Range("D" & LRC) = Worksheets("Results").Range("B" & c.Row)
        Worksheets("Columnsforbox").Range("E" & LRC) = Worksheets("Results").Range("C" & c.Row)
        LRC = LRC + 1
    End If
Next c
```

Comment: Do you only want to look for `UserName` or `UserId` in a specific column of `results` worksheet ?

Comment: If either of the Username or UserID are found in the specified columns I wish for it to carry out the code then go to the next line. For instance currently if Username or UserID is found in Cols A, B, C it will carry out the code 3 times I want the code to only be carried out once.

Comment: @SeanBailey You can't set `c` to other cell in `For Each` loop (well, you can but it will return to next cell of initial cell after `Next`). I might recommend loop through 2d array, you can change values in `For To` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Basicly the same, but now we loop through array:**

```
Dim myArr(), i as Long, j as Long
Dim LR As Long
LR = Workbooks(trackerName).Sheets("Results").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
Dim LRC As Long
LRC = Workbooks(trackerName).Sheets("Columnsforbox").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1
myArr = Range("A4:K" & LR).Value
For i = LBound(myArr,1) To Ubound(myArr,1)
    For j = LBound(myArr,2) To Ubound(myArr,2)
        If myArr(i,j) = UserName Or myArr(i,j) = UserId Then
            Worksheets("Columnsforbox").Range("A" & LRC) = Worksheets("Results").Range("E" & i)
            Worksheets("Columnsforbox").Range("B" & LRC) = Worksheets("Results").Range("D" & i)
            Worksheets("Columnsforbox").Range("C" & LRC) = Worksheets("Results").Range("A" & i)
            Worksheets("Columnsforbox").Range("D" & LRC) = Worksheets("Results").Range("B" & i)
            Worksheets("Columnsforbox").Range("E" & LRC) = Worksheets("Results").Range("C" & i)
            LRC = LRC + 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

Well, you got an idea.

Comment: Thanks or this it is much appreciated! I've never done this type of loop before so thanks for the assistance! One issue is the i starts at 1 so when i am pasting it copies row A instead of 4. I can just but +3 on the end of i and it works however is there a section of the code i can change?

Comment: @SeanBailey
Oh, well, you can manualy add 3 (`& i + 3`) to row, I guess. I can't think of another workaround right now to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution without using loop.

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim rngUserName As Range, rngUserId As Range
    Dim LR As Long, LRC As Long, rowIndex As Long
    Dim srcSht As Worksheet, destSht As Worksheet

    Set srcSht = Workbooks(trackerName).Sheets("Results")       'this is source sheet
    Set destSht = Workbooks(trackerName).Sheets("Columnsforbox") 'this is destination sheet

    LR = srcSht.Cells(srcSht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row     'get last row using column A
    LRC = destSht.Cells(destSht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row  'get last row using column A

    Set rngUserName = Range("A4:K" & LR).Find(UserName, after:=Cells(4, 1), searchdirection:=xlPrevious) 'find user name
    Set rngUserId = Range("A4:K" & LR).Find(UserId, after:=Cells(4, 1), searchdirection:=xlPrevious)   'find user id

    If Not rngUserName Is Nothing And Not rngUserId Is Nothing Then 'if both user name & user id are found
        rowIndex = Application.Max(rngUserName.Row, rngUserId.Row)
    ElseIf Not rngUserName Is Nothing Then                          'if only user name found
        rowIndex = rngUserName.Row
    ElseIf Not Not rngUserId Is Nothing Then                        'if only user id found
        rowIndex = rngUserId.Row
    End If
    MsgBox rowIndex

    destSht.Range("A" & LRC) = srcSht.Range("E" & rowIndex)
    destSht.Range("B" & LRC) = srcSht.Range("D" & rowIndex)
    destSht.Range("C" & LRC) = srcSht.Range("A" & rowIndex)
    destSht.Range("D" & LRC) = srcSht.Range("B" & rowIndex)
    destSht.Range("E" & LRC) = srcSht.Range("C" & rowIndex)
End Sub
```